# Jquery Ajax Call not succeeding

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net, call, webmethod

I have a ajax call to a webmethod but the call always fails.
Here is the below needed code. The LetterReportDataStore class goes to the database and populates and returns a datatable.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
           BindGridView('eastern');

    });

    function BindGridView(r) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "AgencyLetterReport.aspx/GetLetterReportData",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Success');
                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    $("#grdviewe").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].Username +
                                          "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Name + "</td></tr>");
                }
                                },
            error: function () { alert('Failed'); }
        })
    }

    <WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Shared Function GetLetterReportData() As LetterReportData()
    Dim region As String = "eastern"
    Dim list As List(Of LetterReportData) = New List(Of LetterReportData)
    Dim dt As DataTable = LetterReportDataStore.LoadGridData(region)

    For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim _data As LetterReportData = New LetterReportData
        _data.Username = r.Item(0)
        _data.Name = r.Item(1)

        list.Add(_data)
    Next
    Return list.ToArray()
End Function
```

Comment: Are you trying to post to an aspx file?

Comment: yeah its an aspx page

Comment: I have tested the LetterReportDataStore class on retrieving data and it works fine so, its failing somewhere after that. If I replace the webmethod with a simple return string it works. I just cant see anything that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. I changed my webmethod to the below.
I was getting some null values in one of the data fields so I used .Tostring to make it a empty string. I also changed the List to an ArrayList but I think the List will work as well. The problem was the null values I believe.

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Shared Function GetLetterReportData(ByVal region As String) As ArrayList
    'Dim region As String = "eastern"
    Dim list As ArrayList = New ArrayList
    Dim dt As DataTable = LetterReportDataStore.LoadGridData(region)

    For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim _data As LetterReportData = New LetterReportData
        _data.Username = r.Item(0).ToString
        _data.Name = r.Item(1).ToString

        list.Add(_data)
    Next
    Return list
    'Return region
End Function
```

Here is my jquery call

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
        BindGridView('eastern');          
    });

    function BindGridView(r) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "AgencyLetterReport.aspx/GetLetterReportData",
            data: "{'region' : '" + r + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                //alert(data.d[0].Username);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    $("#grdviewe").append("<tr class='GridviewScrollC1Item'><td>" + data.d[i].Username +
                                          "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Name + "</td>" +
                                          "</tr>");
                }
                $('#grdviewe').gridviewScroll({
                    width: $(window).width() - 200,
                    height: $(window).height() - 200
                });
            },
            error: function () { alert('Error on loading data.'); }
        })
    }
```

If you notice this line in the .append call, class='GridviewScrollC1Item'. I had to add this because the gridview columns were losing css on databind and making the columns not line up with the headers.
although the gridview was setup as below. The header css stays but the alternatingrow style and rowstyle is lost. I am working on trying to fix the altering row style now.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdviewe" runat="server" Width="100%" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
     <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#EEF2FF" />
     <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridviewScrollC1Header" /> 
     <RowStyle CssClass="GridviewScrollC1Item" />
 </asp:GridView>
```

Hope this helps anyone!